# What BDD Frameworks are people using with Mono/MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, bdd, monodevelop

I want to start using Behaviour Driven Development (BDD) in Mono/MonoDevelop using a natural language approach like Cucumber or SpecFlow.

Is anyone doing this and, if so, what have they used and was it straightforward to set up.

Thanks

Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpecFlow (www.specflow.org) is a BDD tool for .NET, that is now also running on Mono/MonoDevelop.

You can read about that here: http://groups.google.com/group/specflow/browse_thread/thread/43d32a8f27bfbe92

Br,
Gaspar

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I saw specflow at the prog.net workshops at skillsmatter.com and I'm pleased it is now available for use with monodevelop. I'm looking at rspec in ironruby too but haven't got very far.

Comment: @Neil, we just released the support for Mono/MonoDevelop, you can get more info here:  http://bit.ly/9S0zu5